# How can I configure Windows Defender so that it doesn't prevent moving files it suspects to be a virus?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, virus, windows-defender

Windows Defender prevents moving files it suspects to be a virus:

[image: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus]

> Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus.

How can I configure Windows Defender so that it doesn't prevent moving files it suspects to be a virus?

I'd prefer to not to turn Windows Defender's real time protection entirely:

[image]

Comment: Windows Defender support setting up exclusions. Tried that yet?

Comment: @DanielB Thanks, yes: [How can I configure Windows Defender so that it doesn't delete a file it thinks is a virus/threat, even when I move the file around?](https://superuser.com/q/1823954/116475)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the detected file will also be quarantined,
so not only the move is aborted.

In other words, after the detection of the suspected virus, the file
will no longer exist, except within Defender's quarantine area.

I don't think there is another option than disabling Defender's real-time
protection while you are manipulating this file.