# How can I configure Windows Defender so that it doesn't delete a file it thinks is a virus/threat, even when I move the file around?

Tags: windows-10, virus, windows-defender

I have a file that Windows Defender thinks is a  virus/threat: Windows Defender quarantined it.  I see one can add exclusions:

[image]

If I select "File", Windows Defender will exclude that file path. However, I am moving that file around.

How can I configure Windows Defender so that it doesn't delete a file it thinks is a virus/threat?

Comment: You can't; You have run into a limitation of Windows Defender.  I should add that most AV applications have similar restrictions to their exclusion list.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, good to know, you're welcome to add it as an answer.

Comment: So the solution to this problem is if what’s being detected is NOT actually a virus, you submit the sample to Microsoft, and as a result the file is no longer incorrectly detected as malware.

Comment: @Ramhound "as a result the file is no longer incorrectly detected as malware" how long does that take?

Comment: Well I would simply whitelist the entire directory containing the file, after I submitted it, I have no idea how long it takes I have submitted samples before and have been successful in the file not being detected in the future

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Does any other anti-malware software claim the file is a virus? You can submit it at [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).

Answer (score 0):

As [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound)[mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/1823954/how-can-i-configure-windows-defender-so-that-it-doesnt-delete-a-file-it-thinks#comment2871958_1823954) in the comment section, it is not possible to configure Windows Defender so that it doesn't delete a file it thinks is a virus/threat, even when I move the file around:

> You have run into a limitation of Windows Defender. I should add that most AV applications have similar restrictions to their exclusion list. – [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) [14 hours ago](https://superuser.com/q/1823954/116475)

This makes me wonder [which](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/88619/903) antivirus has this feature.

Comment: The way to configure it is to submit the file as a false-positive.

Answer (score -3):

On several occassions windows 10 defender deleted my files it considered a threat while ignoring the exclusion list.

While I could recover them the first few times through the command line, but the last time it deleted several files permanently and instantly, without me being able to recover them, even through the command line.

This is when I started blocking the "defender" entirely on all my installs, and I recommend others to do the same. One tool for disabling defender (with the option to turn it back whenever you want):
https://www.sordum.org/9480/defender-control-v2-1/

You can use another antivirus program if you want, one which won't overwrite your decisions and cause potentially irrecoverable data loss.

Comment: Uninstalling Windows Defender does not answer the author's question.

Comment: There is no good reason to block Defender, unless setting up a honeypot to intentionally get hacked -- if you install another antimalware suite, that process will *disable* Defender.